# How to place a window application python/tkinter on the screen in a specific place?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I'm trying to place a window python/tkinter application at the bottom left corner of the screen (the bottom left corner of the application must be at the bottom left corner of the screen).
The application is something like this :

```
from tkinter import *

class Dru(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
        self.makeWidgets()

    def makeWidgets(self):
            ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dru = Dru()
    dru.mainloop()
```

It works fine but the windows is placed where the OS wants. If I add "dru.geometry(w*h+x+y)", as I saw on an other question, I get an attibuteError: 'Dru' object has no attribute 'geometry'.
The documentation says that we can use the .geometry attribute for any toplevel window and I thought dru was the toplevel window by default.
Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

A frame is not a toplevel window, and thus doesn't have the `geometry` method. The only widgets that have a `geometry` method are the root window (instance of `Tk`), and instances of the `Toplevel` class.

You should be explicitly creating a root window. Since you are not, you can use introspection to get it. For example:

```
dru = Dru()
dru.winfo_toplevel().geometry("300x300+100+100")
```